# Subset data.table based on observation occurring x times in a column

Tags: r, data.table

With data similar to this:

```
dt <- data.table(id = c("a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d","d","d","d","d"),
                 quantity = c(6,6,7,7,7,8,8,1,1,9,9,9,2,2))
threshold <- 3

    id quantity
 1:  a        6
 2:  a        6
 3:  b        7
 4:  b        7
 5:  b        7
 6:  c        8
 7:  c        8
 8:  c        1
 9:  c        1
10:  d        9
11:  d        9
12:  d        9
13:  d        2
14:  d        2
```

I would like to subset in two ways:

First subset, all `id`s are kept where `quantity` has the same observation at least `threshold` times (3 times) for each `id`. The output should look like this:

```
   id quantity
1:  b        7
2:  b        7
3:  b        7
4:  d        9
5:  d        9
6:  d        9
7:  d        2
8:  d        2
```

Second subset, only rows are kept where `quantity` has the same observation at least `threshold` times (3 times) for each `id`. The output should look like this:

```
   id quantity
1:  b        7
2:  b        7
3:  b        7
4:  d        9
5:  d        9
6:  d        9
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first subset, you could do:

```
dt[id %in% dt[, .N, by = .(id, quantity)][N >= threshold, unique(id)]]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id quantity
> 1:  b        7
> 2:  b        7
> 3:  b        7
> 4:  d        9
> 5:  d        9
> 6:  d        9
> 7:  d        2
> 8:  d        2
> ```

---

And for the second subset:

```
dt[dt[, .N, by = .(id, quantity)][N >= threshold, .(id, quantity)]
   , on = .(id, quantity)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id quantity
> 1:  b        7
> 2:  b        7
> 3:  b        7
> 4:  d        9
> 5:  d        9
> 6:  d        9
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Jaap for your help with this.  I ended up using this because the subset is performed in the `i` which allows me to perform further calculations in the `j` section.

Answer (score 3):

```
# normally I'd use .SD, not .I, but you don't have anything else in your table
second = dt[, if (.N >= threshold) .I, by = .(id, quantity)][, -"V1"]

first = dt[unique(second$id), on = 'id']
```

Answer (score 2):

Playing with `base::rle()`:

First subset:

```
dt[, .SD[max(rle(quantity)[["lengths"]]) >= threshold], id]

   id quantity
1:  b        7
2:  b        7
3:  b        7
4:  d        9
5:  d        9
6:  d        9
7:  d        2
8:  d        2
```

Second subset:

```
dt[,{
      tmp <- rle(quantity)
      ind <- tmp[["lengths"]] >= threshold
      rep(tmp[["values"]][ind], tmp[["lengths"]][ind])
    }, 
   by = id]


   id V1
1:  b  7
2:  b  7
3:  b  7
4:  d  9
5:  d  9
6:  d  9
```